# How to achieve this carousel effect using jQuery (Challenge.. well, for me)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a jquery carousel that resizes the html content (the callouts are background images) Or if there's a way to resize the div whilst resizing the text in the HTML as well, then that would be great too. This will happen on click of the navigation arrows. For a better idea of how the carousel works, it's at the bottom of the page on this website:

www.lightmaker.com  (shown below)

[image]

[image: Callout]

The only difference is, the carousel moves upwards.

Can someone recommend a plugin for such an effect? Or the best way to go about writing a plugin for this.

Thanks!!

Comment: have tried jcarousel? it has a vertical aligment option also [http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/)

Comment: Hi, yes, but if you notice, the images also get resized. So imagine, when I hit the navigation arrow to move to the next callout, the size of the image gets animated. I imagine I could achieve this using animate, but I'm wondering if there's a better way, or a plugin specifically written for the whole effect. I'm not very experienced in plugin development, but now might be a good time to learn, perhaps, if no one has an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also take a look at [Caroufredsel](http://caroufredsel.dev7studios.com/)

Comment: But this does not resize the items!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the recommendation. This plugin, however does not work in the same way as the one on lightmaker.com